# Drop Python Pandas dataframe rows based on date in index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Dataframe that looks like this:

```
                        Facility   PUE   PUEraw   Servers
2016-11-14 00:00:00     6.0        NaN   1.2      5.0 
2016-11-14 00:30:00     6.0        NaN   1.2      5.0 
2016-11-14 01:00:00     6.0        NaN   1.2      5.0
```

etc.

As you can see, the index is date/time. The dataframe is updated with a new value every half hour.

I'm trying to write a script that removes all rows except those that correspond to TODAY's date, for which I am utilising date = dt.datetime.today(). However, I am struggling, partly perhaps because the index also contains the time.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Alternatively, a script that removes all but the last 48 rows would also work for me (the last 48 x half hourly values = the latest day's data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the last rows in a DataFrame with df.tail()

```
df = df.tail(48)
```

For further information:

[Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly and is nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options you can use to extract data on a specific day:

```
df['2016-11-16']
#                     Facility  PUE  PUEraw  Servers
# 2016-11-16 01:00:00      6.0  NaN     1.2      5.0

import datetime
df[df.index.date == datetime.datetime.today().date()]
#                     Facility  PUE  PUEraw  Servers
# 2016-11-16 01:00:00      6.0  NaN     1.2      5.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried this as I've gone with the other method, but it looks good to me.